# Angular textarea directive for integers, floats and scientific notation

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a textarea that holds multiple values(ng-model = array with many positions). And Input(text) for single values(one position array).

I am trying to create a directive(one directive both for the input and the textarea) that allows only to type a value if following pattern is respected:

- Allowed characters: numbers, dots, Ee & -
- Only one dot and Ee per value
- value can not start/end with Ee or dots
- a value can start but not end with minus(-)
- Consecutive dots, minus or Ee are not allowed
- Allowed characters: numbers, dots, Ee & -
- Max 2 minus(-) symbols if separated by Ee
- Minus symbol can only be at the beginning of a value or right after Ee

As I build the directive its getting dirtier so I am hoping that someone shows me a proper way of doing this.

This is what I have so far but many of the rules I wanna apply are not respected like many(-) symbols consecutive, multiple e in the values etc...

Template multivalue textarea:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_float">
  <textarea only-flo class="form-control" rows="{{dbo.attributes[attobj.name].length + 2}}" ng-model="dbo.attributes[attobj.name]" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" ng-change="dbo._isDirty = true"></textarea>
</script>
```

Template single value input:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_float_single">
  <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : theForm.{{ attobj.name }}_{{ dbo._id['value'] }}_{{ dbo.clazz }}.$invalid && !{{ attobj.name }}_{{ dbo._id['value'] }}_{{ dbo.clazz }}.$pristine }">
   <input only-flo type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="dbo.attributes[attobj.name][0]" ng-change="dbo._isDirty = true; forceArray(dbo, attobj);" name="{{ attobj.name }}_{{ dbo._id['value'] }}_{{ dbo.clazz }}" >
  </div>
</script>
```

Directive:

```
  app.directive('onlyFlo', function () {

      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: '?ngModel',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel) return;
              ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {

                  //var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function (s) { return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' ' || s == '.'); }).join('');
                  var digits=  inputValue.replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.').replace(/e{2,}/gmi, 'e').replace(/[^0-9\.\n\r\-e]/gmi, '');
                  //var digits=  inputValue.split(/\s/).filter(function(s){return isNaN(s) ? false : s}).join('\r');

                  console.log('digits: ' + digits);
                  var x = String(digits).split("\n");
                  console.log(x);
                  for (var i=0; i< x.length; i++){
                    if (String(x[i]).indexOf(".") !== -1){
                       console.log('#1 : '+x[i]);

                       var pos= String(x[i]).indexOf(".");
                       console.log('pos: ' +pos);

                       if (String(x[i]).indexOf(".", pos+1) !== -1){
                           console.log('#2 : '+x[i]);
                           var pos2= String(x[i]).indexOf(".", pos+1);
                           console.log('pos2: ' +pos2);


                           console.log('number before dot delete: ' + x[i]);

                           x[i].slice(pos2, pos2+1);
                           x[i] = String(x[i]).slice(0, pos2) + String(x[i].slice(pos2+1, x[i].length +1));
                           console.log('number after dot delete: ' + x[i]);
                        }
                    }  
                  }
                  digits= x.join("\n");
                  console.log('digits: ' + digits);
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(digits);
                  //the one above (setView...) works better avoids the illegal character to appear on double press 
                  //ngModel.$viewValue = digits;
                  ngModel.$render();
                  return digits;
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

Right now what the directive does is:

1 - Replace consecutive dots with one dot. Same with E or e

2 - Remove anything that is not 0-9, -, "\n", "\r", E or e.

3 - Not allow a second dot(a second none consecutive dot)

Obviously this is getting worse as I continue.

I would like a solution that doesn't alter the template side, something that stays within the directive.

I know this is a lot to ask, sorry if I am not explaining my self properly, if so I will try to do better.

The following would be correct values:

- Integers:1,2,3...
- Floats:1.3, 0.3, 0,03...
- Negative integers:-1,-2,-3...
- Negative floats:-1.3, -0.3, -0.03...
- Scientific notation:3e18, 3E18
- Scientific notation:-6e18, -7E18
- Scientific notation:-2.2e18, 2.2E-18
- Scientific notation:-0.22e18, 2.2E-18
- Scientific notation:0.22e-18

Any integer, float or scientific notation represented with e or E.

Comment: Could you give an example as to what is a correct value and what isn't?

Comment: @AlexClem I have added examples of valid values. Thanks for interest

Comment: Well maybe this will be helpful it isn't an answer but might help you solve the problem. Here is a Reg-Ex that matches what you need: `/-?\d+[\.,]?\d*[eE]?-?\d*/g`. Example: https://regex101.com/r/wT2eL8/2